# How to justify mathematical physics result involving Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, mathematical-physics, wave-equation

I was wondering, given classical mathematical physics problem (such as heat equation or wave equation) in which there are solutions written in the form of a Fourier series. To solve these problems, I usually try to separate the variables, then derive etc. I mean, I basically suppose that the solution is regular enough to let me do such things. Then when I have finished and found the solution as Fourier series, how can I conclude that the operations done to find that are justified?

For instance, let's take $ \partial_t ^2 u- \partial_x ^2 u=0$ , a wave equation. Separating variables and summing I find $u(t,x)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (a_k \cos(kt)+b_k \sin(kt)) \sin(kx)$. This is the general form, although with some conditions (for instance initial condition or border condition) it usually is simplified. If I were to prove that this solution is continuous, differentiable and basically has all the properties that I supposed it had , I would require some sort of regularity in the border/initial conditions.

I wonder: is there some way to generalise this or every problem is on its own? I mean, it kinda bothers me to do things like "yeah, let's suppose I can do this and then let's prove I could", but maybe it really is how these problem are solved.

Comment: When solving things like this, we aren't looking for all solutions, just _a_ solution. So by solving like this, you get the general form of all _separable_ solutions. You only implement such operations that fit the physical problem you are solving, since you are only looking for solutions that make sense physically.

Comment: @JohnDoe yeah, indeed there are also traveling waves that give a solution. The fact I have difficulty to get over with is that when searching for a separable solution, writing it as a Fourier series, we just don't bother to be formal and just postpone the problem. Maybe this is physically correct and it always works, but from a rigorous point of view it just kinda bothers me. But again, maybe this is just how these things are supposed to be solved and in fact there is no bettere way, so it may be just a my problem

Comment: AFAIK, there is no uniqueness theorem for the solutions of PDEs as there is for ODEs.  When you find a solution set to a PDE there could be other solutions, so you can't generally justify what you've done as complete, just that the solution set you have come up with works.

Comment: " ..can I conclude that the operations done to find that are justified? " from the physics or mathematics point of view ?. Because in any case the first question is whether the mathematical model fits the physical phenomenon and up to which extent/assumption, etc. Then, like indicated in the answer below, the physics will dictate the conditions at the contour (in space and/or time) and so if the class of solutions found is suitable for the model.

Comment: @AndyWalls There are not *general* uniqueness theorems that apply to all PDEs, but for equations like the heat, wave, and Laplace equations in reasonably nice domains, it is pretty easy to prove uniqueness for initial/boundary value problems using e.g. energy methods.

Comment: Ok, so I think I just have to get used to it. About uniqueness, like said by @Montie above, we have not been shown general methods (because there aren't any), but some tricks indeed work (we have seen the energy and a few others)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are solving also includes endpoint conditions $u(t,0)=u(t,\pi)=0$. And $u(0,x)=f(x),u_t(0,x)=g(x)$ must be known. Then you have uniqueness. If there were two such solutions, $u,v$, then $w=u-v$ would satisfy
$$
       w_{tt}=w_{xx},\;\; w(0,x)=0,\;\; w_t(0,x)=0.
$$
There are tricks you can use to show that $w$ must be $0$, which then proves that $u=v$. The more significant issue is knowing that functions can be expanded in trigonometric series, and then showing that the resulting series has enough regularity to apply the chosen uniqueness trick. But, once this is done, you have a solution, and you know that solution is unique among those with sufficient regularity.

Comment: Yeah we also have seen some of these methods. My only wonder was if it were common to postpone some hypothesis to justify things used or it was just a sort of didactic way our teacher showed us how to solve these problems. I mean, in exercises we practically never bother about justifying formally all steps, because we always assume "enough regularity". In fact, this is most likely the right thing to do, otherwise exercises would be pages long! Again, it is just my spirit of "rigorous" mathmatician who would like to prove everything before using it that is a bit bothered. But he'll deal with it

Comment: @tommy1996q : Learning to solve problems first is probably the best way to go. Then proving enough regularity. Proving uniqueness could come first or after finding solutions; this is typically not as hard. Trying to make sense of the solution methods directly led to a great deal of modern Analysis, including integration theory, Topology, Functional Analysis, Spectral Theory, and Fourier Analysis. So justifying the methods can't really come first as a practical matter.